# iTextSharp PDF Base font size with XMLWorker

Tags: css, pdf-generation, itext

How can I set my PDF body font size "6.6pt" using **XMLWorker**?

I have achieved using **HTMLWorker** as like below,

```
var style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "6.6pt");  
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
htmlWorker.SetStyleSheet(style);
```

But how can I do this with **XMLWorker**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code:

```
var style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "6.6pt");
```

was a poor version of applying CSS to the HTML you were parsing.

When using XML Worker, you can use real CSS.

Go the official web site and take a closer look at the [examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables), where we have CSS such as:

```
<table style="font-size:10pt">
```

Html: [table10.html](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables#978-table10.html); Java: [ParseHtmlTable10.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables#966-parsehtmltable10.java); PDF: [html_table_10.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_html_table_10.pdf)

Or CSS such as:

```
p           { font-size: 11px; font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif; color: #040404; background-color: #FFFFEE; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 10px; }
h1          { font-size: 17px; color: #FFA500; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: #0000EE; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-left:10px; }    
h2          { font-size: 15px; color: #0055AA; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 16px;  background-color:#FFCC66; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px; padding-left:10px; }
h3          { font-size: 15px; color: #660000; margin-bottom: 8px;  margin-top: 15px; }
h4          { font-size: 12px; color: black; margin-bottom: 8px;  margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 8px; font-style: normal; }
code        { font-size: 12px; margin-left: 16px; padding-left:16px}
```

HTML: [paragj.html](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables#977-paragj.html); Java: [ParseHtmlTable6.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables#973-parsehtmltable6.java); PDF: [html_table_6.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_html_table_6.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! That's appreciated!